# sum() function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, sum, iteration

I am confused with the following syntax:

```
def getClassiness(self):
        classiness_points = {
            "tophat": 2,
            "bowtie": 4,
            "monocle": 5
        }

        classiness = sum(classiness_points.get(item, 0) for item in self.items)
        return classiness
```

I understand the following one, but both are correct.

```
def getClassiness(self):
        classiness_points = {
            "tophat": 2,
            "bowtie": 4,
            "monocle": 5
        }
        classiness = 0
        for item in self.items:
            classiness += classiness_points.get(item, 0)
        return classiness
```

I guess what I do not understand is how a generator expression works. I understand that sum() takes an iterable as its argument and returns the sum of the elements. I would have thought of:

```
 classiness = sum(classiness_points.get(item, 0) for item in self.items)
        return classiness
```

better this way,

```
 classiness = sum( for item in self.items: classiness_points.get(item, 0))
        return classiness
```

Because I am used to place the expression after the *for loop*
It must be just syntax.

Comment: Please format your code. Thanks for giving a breakdown of your best understanding, it'll help to provide a relevant answer! However, you haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *"It must be just syntax."* - yes, this is **generator expression** syntax: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=comprehension#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this input:

```
classiness_points = {'tophat': 2, 'bowtie': 4, 'monocle': 5}
items = ['tophat', 'monocle', 'shirt']
```

What a generator does is almost the same as a list comprehension:

```
[classiness_points.get(item, 0) for item in items]
# [2, 5, 0]
```

Except it only produces the items when requested, which `sum` is doing by iterating over the generator's items.

```
sum(classiness_points.get(item, 0) for item in items)
# 7
```

So, this is more or less equivalent to:

```
sum([classiness_points.get(item, 0) for item in items])
```

Except in one case, python pre-generates a list to pass to `sum`. In the other `sum` is iterating by itself over the generators' elements.